# Stuck at Installing "grub2 package"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, hp

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.1 as my second OS for my HP Pavilion x360. The installation method I am using is "install alongside windows boot manager".

My installation stops at `"installing grub2 packages"`. The console would say "`Installing for x86_64-efi platform.`" and loops over "`Warning: Source ID n was not found when attempting to remove it`" where n is some number.

I have tried installing with and without secure boot and legacy mode and created multiple bootable USBs using rufus, Universal USB installer, startup disk creator (via ubuntu VirtualBox) and Etcher, but the results are the same.

I have also tried installing Ubuntu just by itself and that works, but I still need a bootloader to actually boot into the OS.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI from HP for your system? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the summary report ( not full report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I have updated my BIOS, but the problem persists. Here's the boot-repair summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bHPKQjtY4b/

Comment: Are you able to boot either ubuntu entry or hard drive entry in UEFI menu?  But report is not showing /boot/grub/grub.cfg nor /etc/fstab which are required. From live installer can you see those files in your install?

Comment: No, the Ubuntu entry in the UEFI menu just brings me to the grub console. I have tried using commands to attempt to boot into Ubuntu from the console, but it just brings me to "try ubuntu without installing" menu. 
How do I check if the "/boot/grub/grub.cfg" and "/etc/fstab" are in my install?

Comment: From live installer, can you click on the install in your hard drive and drill down to those files? Others with HP360 are having issues: HP Pavillion X360 13-a220nw
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359510 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2407615

Comment: I didn't access my live USB via the live version of Ubuntu (would not let me access the disk), but I was able to access it through my VirtualBox of Ubuntu. I am able to find boot/grub/grub.cfg, but not /etc/fstab.

Comment: Then install is not complete. You can create your own fstab and chroot into system and do full updates. But probably easier just to reinstall.

Comment: Just to clarify, I need to remake the live USB which is used to install Ubuntu on my laptop? What if creating another live USB also results in the absence of /etc/fstab?

Comment: While you may be able to use same Flash drive, better to start over, just in case it was not written correctly & that is the issue. If UEFI:UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formatted flash drive partition & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Comment: Ok, I have made the uefi usb from the guide and the install is still stuck at "installing grub2 package". The console keeps saying "/usr/lib/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:7: Warning: Source ID XXXXX was not found when attempting to remove it GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)" and
"/usr/lib/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:133: Warning: Source ID XXXXX was not found when attempting to remove it GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)"

Comment: See last comment here on setting UEFI password and trusting grub/ubuntu boot file. This is like Acer, but have not seen it on installer nor any other system than Acer. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=265615 If that works, we can post as answer so it is here in AskUbuntu.

Comment: My HP UEFI does not have a "trusted file". Should I just install a different bootloader such as rEFInd? I doubt Grub wants to work with my particular machine.

Comment: I have used rEFInd as emergency boot. It seems to work well when system seems to have issues. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: Alright, I can boot into my ubuntu using refind now. Thanks so much for trying to help me with grub2, even if it didn't work out in the end. :)